# NullPointerException when recording is stopped android

Tags: java, android, audio, recording

I'm trying to make an app that starts recording when a button is clicked, and when is clicked again it stops recording. I don't think I have problems when I'm recording, but when I click the button again the application crashes with NullPointerException and it is said that stop is called in invalid state 1

My code:

```
package com.example.victwo;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.media.MediaRecorder;

public class Audio {
    private String path;

    MediaRecorder myAudioRecorder = null;

    public Audio(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public void play() {

    }

    public void startRecording() {
        myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(path);

        try {
            myAudioRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        myAudioRecorder.start();
    }

    public void stopRecording() {
        myAudioRecorder.stop();
        myAudioRecorder.release();
        myAudioRecorder = null;
    }

}
```

This is the code from the activity where I call the Audio Class methods:

```
    case R.id.action_record:
        Audio recAndPlay = new Audio(this.path + "/" + this.title);

        if(flag == 0) {
            Log.d("RECORD", "START");
            flag = 1;
            if(title.equals("")) {
                setTitle();
            }
            recAndPlay.startRecording();
            return true;
        }

        if(flag == 1) {
            Log.d("RECORD", "STOP");
            recAndPlay.stopRecording();
        }
        return true;
```

The logcat:

```
04-05 14:02:58.909: E/AndroidRuntime(5730): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-05 14:02:58.909: E/AndroidRuntime(5730): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-05 14:02:58.909: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at com.example.victwo.Audio.stopRecording(Audio.java:41)
04-05 14:02:58.909: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at com.example.victwo.NoteActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(NoteActivity.java:158)
04-05 14:02:58.909: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2205)
04-05 14:02:58.909: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:372)
04-05 14:02:58.909: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivity.java:244)
04-05 14:02:58.909: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:339)
04-05 14:02:58.909: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivity.java:130)
04-05 14:02:58.909: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:344)
04-05 14:02:58.909: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:777)
04-05 14:02:58.909: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
04-05 14:02:58.909: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:922)
04-05 14:02:58.909: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:544)
04-05 14:02:58.909: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:105)
04-05 14:02:58.909: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
04-05 14:02:58.909: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
04-05 14:02:58.909: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-05 14:02:58.909: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-05 14:02:58.909: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-05 14:02:58.909: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-05 14:02:58.909: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-05 14:02:58.909: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-05 14:02:58.909: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-05 14:02:58.909: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-05 14:02:58.909: E/AndroidRuntime(5730):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is line number 158 in `NoteActivity.java`

Comment: The code you posted looks fine. Maybe it's the way you are handling the Audio class object? Maybe the listener for the button that starts and stops recording creates new object each time is clicked and therefore stopRecording is invoked without startRecording() earlier?

Answer (score 2):

Initialize your media player in out side of startRecording()

```
 myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
```

Modify your code like following

```
public class Audio {
private String path;




MediaRecorder myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

public Audio(String path) {
    this.path = path;
}

public void play() {

}

public void startRecording() {

    myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
    myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(path);

    try {
        myAudioRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    myAudioRecorder.start();
}

public void stopRecording() {
    myAudioRecorder.stop();
    myAudioRecorder.release();
    myAudioRecorder = null;
}
}
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: When i initialize myAudioRecorder outside the method, this is given:
04-05 15:16:54.630: E/AndroidRuntime(8569): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-05 15:16:54.630: E/AndroidRuntime(8569): java.lang.IllegalStateException
04-05 15:16:54.630: E/AndroidRuntime(8569):  at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

The `myAudioRecorder` must be null at the time you call `stopRecording()`. I can not judge from your code why (do you call `stopRecording()` twice?). If you post more code I might be able to help you. You could also surround the statements in the `stopRecording()`method with a check:

```
public void stopRecording() {
    if(myAudioRecorder != null){
       myAudioRecorder.stop();
       myAudioRecorder.release();
       myAudioRecorder = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void stopRecording() {
        if (null != recorder) {
            recorder.stop();
            recorder.reset();
            recorder.release();

            recorder = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This would be much more useful if it explained how it answers the question. Just providing a lump of code may not help the asker or anyone else understand the original problem.

Comment: post your activity code where you are using this method and i will try to help further

Answer (score 0):

please check if MediaRecorder object is not null before stopping it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are taking the right approach. why declare media player as null in the beginning. initialise in first and when done use methods of media player class to release/reset it.

also before you start using mediaplayer use if(){...}block to check whether it is initialised. example below;

```
   private void stopRecording() {
      if (myAudioRecorder != null) {
        myAudioRecorder.stop();
        myAudioRecorder.reset();
        myAudioRecorder.release();

        myAudioRecorder = null;
     }
  }
```

Comment: It is said that stop is called in invalid state 1

Comment: post your activity code where you are using this method and i will try to help further

Answer (score 0):

**Another reason** could be, that it was already stopped, and then you are re-using `.stop()` function, which causes problems, check your logic and code...